# Plot arrays same extension Matlotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've several time series stored in numpy arrays with de same extension (*.corr.npy). I would like to plot it in the same figure with matplotlib.

Now I'm plotting like that:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as num
a=num.load('100.corr.npy')
b=num.load('2345.corr.npy')
...
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
...
plt.savefig('corr', papertype='a4', orientation='portrait', format='ps')
```

But as I have a lot of arrays I would like to make a cycle for plotting. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) standard module shines!
It will generate lists of files matching simple format rules.

In your case:

```
import glob
import numpy as np

array_files = glob.glob('*.corr.npy')
for fname in array_files:
    x = np.load(fname)
    plt.plot(x)
```

`glob.glob` will operate in the current working directory, so ýou might want to use the absolute path instead:

```
ROOT_DIR = '/some/path/to/array/files/'
array_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, '*.corr.npy'))
```

---

I see you use `num` as an alias for `numpy`. I think `np` is the de-facto standard of numpy aliasing, so you could consider using that instead.